# How to achieve @OneToOne User and role?

Tags: jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have the following tables:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|                user               |
+------------------------------------
| id |  username   |    role_id     |
+----+-------------+----------------+
|  1 |    user1    |       1        |
+----+-------------+----------------+

+-----------------------------------+
|                role               |
+------------------------------------
|    role_id      |   role_name     |
+-----------------+-----------------+
|       1         |       GUEST     |
+-----------------+-----------------+
|       2         |       USER      |
+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Each user have 1 role. Fields looks like this:

User.java

```
   @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID")
   private Role role;
```

Role.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ROLE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int id;
```

The `Role` table will already be populated with only 2 roles. When I try to add a new user, a new record gets saved inside `Role` table. This is not the behavior I'm seeking. I don't want values to be written to `Role` table (unless maybe the the value being added doesn't exist in the table).

Any idea how to achieve this properly? Pretty sure this is simple, but I'm new to JPA.

**edit**: Code to add user

```
user = new User("JoDoe",new Role("USER"));
user = repository.save(user);
```

So as pointed out by the comments, it's because I'm creating a new Role every time. Can anybody point out the proper flow please? Should I first retrieve a Role from the db via `RoleDao` for example, and then assign that object to the new user? Or is there any other way that I'm missing?

Comment: so post your code to create a new User, and particularly what Role object you are giving it ... because, after all, that is what you say you have an error with

Comment: I assume you create a new role instance when saving the user. Due to cascading the (detached) role gets saved as well...

Comment: I'm on mobile now but yes im creating a new object of Role every time. Should i first fetch the object from db via RoleDao then assign it to the user? I thought there is a way to configure it directly via the Model classes and annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, since several users can have the same role, you don't have a OneToOne, but a ManyToOne.

Second, if you create a new Role, without even assigning it an ID, and create a User with that new Role, since the association has `cascade = ALL`, JPA will indeed create persist this new Role. How is it supposed to know that what you actually want to do is find the role which has the same name in database and assign that role to the new User?

That's what you must do. Assuming you have the ID of the role of the new User, what you need is

```
Role existingRole = em.getReference(roldId);
User user = new Role(existingRole);
em.persist(user);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing this now `user = new User("JoeDoe",roleDao.findOne(1));` and it's working as intended. However I noticed that in your example you use `EntityManager`. Should I stop using dao and look into `EntityManager`? Or what I'm doing is fine?

Comment: No, what you have is fine. A DAO is a level of abstraction above the EntityManager.

Comment: I also have to remove `CascadeType.ALL` from Role so when I delete a user, the associated `Role` doesn't get deleted. Right? Excuse my ignorance, new to all of this :)

Comment: Yes, indeed. Using cascade=ALL on a ManyToXxx association doesn't make sense.